# Pyspark - Error related to SparkContext - no attribute _jsc

Tags: python, pyspark

Unsure of what the issue is with this. I've seen similar issues regarding this problem, but nothing that solves my issue. Full Error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/computer/PycharmProjects/spark_test/spark_test/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    sqlcontext = SQLContext(sc)
  File "C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\context.py", line 74, in __init__
    self._jsc = self._sc._jsc
AttributeError: type object 'SparkContext' has no attribute '_jsc'
```

Here is the simple code I am trying to run:

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext as sc

sqlcontext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlcontext.read.json('random.json')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Spark Shell, you will notice that `SparkContext` is already created.

Otherwise, you can create the SparkContext by **importing, initializing** and providing the configuration settings. In your case you only passed the `SparkContext` to `SQLContext`

```py
import pyspark

conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
# conf.set('spark.app.name', app_name) # Optional configurations

# init & return
sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
sqlcontext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlcontext.read.json('random.json')
```